# Application giving access violation when run in Load Runner

Tags: visual-c++, windbg, performance-testing, loadrunner

When I tested my applications performance in Load runner I get access violation.The Load runner just reports that there is a access violation. But I don't know where it is happening,so I tried to reproduce it simulating load runner by creating a multi threaded program and get the stack trace in Windbg, but the access violation is not happening in it. So now I am stuck here. Load runner experts can you suggest how to debug this access violation?Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Can you please use web_set_user and pass the credentials and check if it works.

Comment: What credentials should i have to pass. And will that give a stack trace of the access violation? Pls bear with me ,Im not a LR expert.Can you explain more pls.

Comment: As you are not an expert, I have a couple of questions: (1) Has your management funded training for you & (2) have they provided you with an internal mentor until you hit a defined mark for expertise in the discipline?  If not, then your odds of success are dire and that responsibility lies directly with your management.

Comment: @JamesPulley Im actually a developer. This issue was reported by performance team.this issue happens in LR only .but I was able to reproduce it in my multithreaded program after several tries(no effiecient way to do it,patience only helped me) and got the stack trace and fixed it yesterday.thanks everyone for the answers

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a LoadRunner bug.

If the crash happens in your application when recording, you can attach windbg to it after recording started.

If crash happens during replay, I'm afraid you have to open a service request.

Comment: "It sounds like a LoadRunner bug."  There is not enough evidence noted to make such a statement.  In all likelihood there are other elements in play, such as the site requiring a level of security not yet set in the code for the virtual user.

Answer (score 0):

Examine the performance with a control element, such as the sample flight reservation application.  It is important to understand whether you have an application specific issue (which is my hypothesis based upon the expressed error) or you have an installation and configuration issue with your software.

By using a controlled application, such as the sample flight reservation application, you will be able to determine whether LoadRunner is operating as expected  and where you need to turn your attention to address the error at hand.

Also, ask the managers of the site instance you are attempting to develop against whether any additional security related to Windows integrated security or authorization headers are required for you to access the site.